# in my edit text box last digit is not clear.if trying to clear app unfortunately stop message will come

Tags: java, android

05-11 11:44:18.185 25221-25221/com.example.jagan.mainapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.jagan.mainapplication, PID: 25221
                         java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)     at com.example.jagan.mainapplication.BottomBar2Activities.Add2Tab$1.afterTextChanged(Add2Tab.java:57)  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9078)   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11739)
                                                                                       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:976)
                                                                                       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:520)  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:216) at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
                                                                                       at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)
                                                                                       at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)
                                                                                       at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)
                                                                                       at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
                                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6989)
                                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6750)
                                                                                       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3200)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9027)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:523)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1594)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2735)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1826)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2947)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2613)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4918)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4873)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4337)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4482)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4364)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4539)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4337)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4364)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4337)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6938)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6811)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6782)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3986)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Activi

Comment: without seeing the stacktrace for your error, we can´t help...

Comment: but I guess that edit1.getText().toString() does not return a parsable value. It is maybe not a digit string that matches an integer..

Comment: It seem like a NumberFormat error. Try to check if your EditText is empty before parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

try this

check edittext length before convert to integer

```
  final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   if(edit1.getText().toString().length()>0){
                   final int value = Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText().toString());
                    if (value < 90 || value > 200 ) {
    //                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter 90-200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edit1.setError("enter 90-200");


                    }
                   }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank u somuch for u r replay.now its working thank u dr.

Comment: Glad it worked.Please accept my answer.You can also visit : https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NumberFormatException` that means, the `String` you are tryng to parse into an `Integer` is not a valid digit String. In your case, it is just empty. There are several ways to check if the `String` is valid, for example:

```
String number = edit1.getText().toString();
if(!number.isEmpty())
```

which checks if the text you get from `edit1` is empty. But this could not the only problem, you can face more user issues like input letters instead of numbers, or a decimal number and so on. The best to avoid such scenarios is to catch the error instead of check the `String` against all possible reasons:

```
int value = 0;
String number = edit1.getText().toString();
try{
value = Integer.parseInt(number);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a valid number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Usually, you should avoid in code that some error comes up, but in cases like this, you can avoid many wrong scenarios at once.